Calculate Median Nesting Date (Quantile) on R
I have a database containing a column with dates that I recorded sea turtle nesting activities and I am trying to calculate the Median Nesting Date (Quantile) on R.
The result is giving integer numbers instead of dates:
qant = do.call('rbind',tapply(as.Date(df.gr.yr$Date, format = "%Y %m%d"),df.gr.yr$Years, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975), type = 1))

Date and years of monitoring
I was expecting to have quantiles of 25% and 97% for each year of Monitoring represented in dates...but R is returning numbers
Screenshot
